# Swift optional and default value for double

Tags: swift, option-type

I am trying to set the value of a text provider based on a double from an optional response. I feel there should be a shorter way to do this but when I try using a default value it insists the default must be a double and I want a string to replace it.

Pseudo code:

```
If we have a current value 
    use it
 else
    use "--"
```

What I thought would work

```
let currentValue = uvProduct.currentValue()?.value
currentTextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: String( currentValue ?? "--" ))
```

Current attempt

```
let currentValue = uvProduct.currentValue()?.value
let currentTextProvider : CLKSimpleTextProvider

if (currentValue != nil){
    currentTextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: String( currentValue! ))
} else {
    currentTextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "--")
}
```

Comment: Where is it insisting you need a double?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a good place to use `map` on an *optional*:

```
let currentValue = uvProduct.currentValue()?.value
let currentTextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: currentValue.map(String.init) ?? "--")
```

`map` will return `nil` if the *optional* is `nil`, otherwise it will run the provided closure.  In this case, `String.init` takes a `Double` and returns a `String`.  The *nil-coalescing operator* `??` unwraps the result of `map` (which is a `String?`) or replaces it with `"--"` if `currentValue` is `nil`.

Comment: This code no longer works because Xcode throws an error about the ambiguous use of init

Comment: Try `let currentTextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: currentValue.map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "--")` or `let currentTextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: currentValue.map { "\($0)" } ?? "--")`